# Preserve line breaks when adding template literal to html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks, template-literals, end-of-line

How would I preserve the end-of-line characters in the `str` template literal below when adding to html?

```js
let str = `

          Woke up this morning,
           
           ate a baguette,
           
           smiled at a person and they smiled back.`

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = `<div>Dreamfit:</div><div>${str}<div>`
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve just the line breaks, or all whitespace including indentation?

Comment: I agree with Joan Albert's answer, but also see the summary table at the end of the [Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) section for the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property at MDN. `pre`, `pre-wrap`, `pre-line`, and `break-spaces` will all preserve line breaks, so which you use depends on _what else_ you want to preserve.

Comment: @StephenP ambivalent on indents - thanks for extra options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style your `div` with `white-space: pre-wrap`:

So your code should look like:

```js
let str = `

          Woke up this morning, 
ate a baguette,
           
           smiled at a person and they smiled back.`

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = `<div>Dreamfit:</div><div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">${str}<div>`
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: I vote yes, this is the right way to do it ... but also, I always advocate for using _classes_ rather than inline styles, so I'd recommend `...<div class="dream">${str}</div>` or whatever class makes sense to describe _what_ the div contains (classes should be about _semantics_, not styles)

Comment: @StephenP totally agree with you, I just didn't want to add more complexity to my answer and focus on resolving the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `<pre>` tag:

```js
let str = `<pre>

          Woke up this morning,
           
           ate a baguette,
           
           smiled at a person and they smiled back.</pre>`

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = `<div>Dreamfit:</div><div>${str}<div>`
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: That works thanks & +1, but I'd very much like to not add anything else to `str`

Comment: You could put the pre around the $str as well, that way you don't have to modify the var

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) also as:

```js
let str = `

          Woke up this morning,
           
           ate a baguette,
           
           smiled at a person and they smiled back.`

let html = `<div>Dreamfit:</div><div>${str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')}<div>`

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = html
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

See the essential part separately here: `str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')`.